# Is there any way to register custom background images like header images?

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer, custom-background

I wonder if there exists a quick way to register custom background images as simple as we do with the custom headers.

```
$header_images = array(
  'ferrari' => array(
    'url'           => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/ferrari.jpg',
    'thumbnail_url' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/ferrari.jpg',
    'description'   => 'Ferrari',
  ),
  'harley-davidson' => array(
    'url'           => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/harley-davidson.jpg',
    'thumbnail_url' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/harley-davidson.jpg',
    'description'   => 'Harley Davidson',
  ),
);
register_default_headers( $header_images );
```

Google fetched me nothing but [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/18623/18623.4.diff), couldn't get anything meaningful out of it. Is anyone doing this? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

We can add Custom background images support to theme in WordPress using the process similar to registering default headers. Here is your quick way!

```
$defaults = array(
    'default-color'          => '',
    'default-image'          => '%1$s/images/background.jpg',
    'default-repeat'         => 'repeat',
    'default-position-x'     => 'left',
        'default-position-y'     => 'top',
        'default-size'           => 'auto',
    'default-attachment'     => 'scroll',
    'wp-head-callback'       => '_custom_background_cb',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => ''
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults );
```

There are two more ways to implement it:

1 - We can do this by playing some tricks and load preset of images.

add_filter('body_class','random_background_images');
function random_background_images($classes) {

```
// Generate Random number from 1 to 10.  
$background_class = 'background_' . rand(1,10);

$classes[] = $background_class;

return $classes;
```

}

Add the code above to your wordpress themes functions.php file. It will add a random body class from background_1 to background_10

now you can add css for them as you want.

body.background_1 {
       background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background1.jpg");
}
body.background_2 {
       background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background2.jpg");
}
body.background_3 {
       background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background3.jpg");
}

2 - jQuery example:

var images = [
       "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53453ebbe4b0d46770eb7505/5345482be4b01730378288f7/54b3a45de4b0d7856db8059e/1421059173445/", 
       "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53453ebbe4b0d46770eb7505/5345482be4b01730378288f7/54c5f3c8e4b0d7a7fa84acc2/1422274046633/", 
       "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53453ebbe4b0d46770eb7505/5345482be4b01730378288f7/54a78e9ae4b00f7c5fb39c4a/1421997719378/"
     ];

```
 var imgCount = images.length;

 var randNumber=Math.floor((Math.random() * imgCount) + 1);

 imgURL = "url('" + images[randNumber-1] + "')";

 var body=document.getElementById('collection-542ba4a1e4b032a0dde82b31');
 body.style.backgroundImage=imgURL;
 body.style.backgroundSize="100% auto";
 body.style.backgroundRepeat="no-repeat";
```

}());

If you need any further assistance, please let us know! 
Happy coding

Comment: Well, I am already doing this, and thinking of something a step further to it. I am looking for presets, as we do with the custom header images. `register_default_headers` is the function in question here.

Comment: Please see the updated solution above. It has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for it! As explained by Progostech

```
$defaults = array(
    'default-color'          => '',
    'default-image'          => '',
    'default-repeat'         => 'repeat',
    'default-position-x'     => 'left',
        'default-position-y'     => 'top',
        'default-size'           => 'auto',
    'default-attachment'     => 'scroll',
    'wp-head-callback'       => '_custom_background_cb',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => ''
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults );
```